# Calculate multiple columns based on threshold

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

data

```
data=data.frame("student"=c(1,2,3,4,5),
"score1"=c(77,NA,52,99,89),
"score2"=c(95,89,79,89,73),
"score3"=c(92,52,73,64,90),
"score4"=c(84,57,78,81,66),
"score1x"=c(0,NA,0,1,1),
"score2x"=c(1,1,0,1,0),
"score3x"=c(1,0,0,0,1),
"score4x"=c(1,0,0,1,0))
```

I have data with student id and score1-score4 and hope to create score1x-score4x in a simple fast way. The rule is if say score1 is less than 80 then score1x is 0 otherwise it is 1.
I can do this by: `data$score1x=ifelse(score1<80,0,1)` but am wondering is there a way to do this for all of them at the same time to create score1x-score4x more quickly?

---

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
cbind(data, (data[, 1:4] < 80) * 1)
```

Comment: I think `as.numeric(data[, 1:4] < 80)` is slightly clearer and roughly as fast

Comment: Might I suggest `cbind(data, (data[, 2:5] > 80) * 1)`. OP wanted a 0 if the value is less than 80.

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` solution:

```
setDT(data)
cols <- paste0("score", 1:4)
data[, paste0(cols, "x") := lapply(.SD, function(x) as.integer(x > 80)), .SDcols = cols]
data

   student score1 score2 score3 score4 score1x score2x score3x score4x
1:       1     77     95     92     84       0       1       1       1
2:       2     NA     89     52     57      NA       1       0       0
3:       3     52     79     73     78       0       0       0       0
4:       4     99     89     64     81       1       1       0       1
5:       5     89     73     90     66       1       0       1       0
```

Comment: thanks so much i get this error: Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , `:=`(paste0(cols, "y"), lapply(.SD, function(x) as.integer(x >  : 
  unused argument (.SDcols = cols)

Comment: sorry, forgot that you need to `setDT()`, convert the `data.frame` into a `data.table` format.

Comment: @sondri_baldur thanks so much it works very good but actually i realized my question was not exactly as sharp as it needs to be

Answer (score 0):

You could use this `dplyr` solution which creates new variables for columns with `"score"` in the name using `mutate_at()`, then uses `rename_at()` to change `"_x"` to `"x"` at the end of the column names:

```
library(dplyr)

data[1:5] %>%
  mutate_at(vars(contains("score")), list(x = ~as.integer(. > 80))) %>%
  rename_at(vars(contains("_x")), ~gsub("_", "", ., fixed = T))

  student score1 score2 score3 score4 score1x score2x score3x score4x
1       1     77     95     92     84       0       1       1       1
2       2     NA     89     52     57      NA       1       0       0
3       3     52     79     73     78       0       0       0       0
4       4     99     89     64     81       1       1       0       1
5       5     89     73     90     66       1       0       1       0
```

Comment: thanks so much it works very good but actually i realized my question was not exactly as sharp as it needs to be